# How to call a method when methodname is a function parameter

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
def API(request, selector):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        API2 = callback(f, user, password)
        API2.selector()
```

In this case `callback` is a Class which is initiating in API2. Inside the Class `callback` there is a function called `register`. I want to call `register()` via `API2.selector()`. So `API(request, register)` should result in `API2.register()`.

Is something like this possible?

The only why I could think of is if/elif statements.

Finlay I would like it to work when I make a POST to '.../API/register' it will return `API2.register()`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can write:

```
getattr(API2, selector)()
```

which uses the built-in [`getattr`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#getattr) function. In this case you should provide `selector` as text, so:

```
getattr(API2, 'register')()
```

If you want to return the result you should use `return`:

```
def API(request, selector):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        API2 = callback(f, user, password)
        return getattr(API2, selector)()
```